# How to use Recursive query in db2

Tags: sql, db2

I am learning to use recursive query in db2, got a problem online to print following pattern

```
 * 
 ** 
 *** 
 **** 
 ***** 
 ****** 
 ******* 
 ******** 
 ********* 
 ********** 
 ***********
```

upto 20 level, solved it in Oracle using following query

```
select lpad('*', level, '*') result  from dual  connect by level <= 20
```

but got no idea how to do it in db2, would really appreciate any help.

Also how to do it in reverse order, means how to print stars pyramid from 20th to 1st level?

Comment: what platform and version of DB2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct query for db2, using `REPEAT` instead of `LPAD`

```
with x(id,val) as 
(
 select 1, REPEAT('*',1) from sysibm.sysdummy1
 union all
 select id+1, REPEAT('*',id+1) from x where id < 20
)
select val from x
```

```
with x(id,val) as 
(
 select 20, REPEAT('*',20) from sysibm.sysdummy1
 union all
 select id-1, REPEAT('*',id-1) from x where id > 1
)
select val from x
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `dual` with `sysibm.sysdummy1`

```
select lpad('*', level, '*') result  
from sysibm.sysdummy1   
connect by level <= 20
```

Comment: The `connect by` syntax is only supported when Oracle compatibility mode is enabled in DB2, in which case there's also a `DUAL` table, so the original query would simply run unchanged.

Comment: It is not working for me, DB client throwing error on connect by, what is the replacement of 'connect by' in db2?

Answer (score 0):

Recursive query for printing 1 to 20 `*`s

```
with x(id,val) as 
(
   select 1 as id,lpad('*',1,'*') as val from sysibm.sysdummy1
   union all
   select id+1,lpad('*',id+1,'*') from x where id < 20
)
select val from x
```

Recursive query for printing 20 to 1 `*`s

```
with x(id,val) as 
(
 select lpad('*',20,'*') as val,20 as id from sysibm.sysdummy1
 union all
 select lpad('*',id-1,'*'),id-1 from x where id > 1
)
select val from x
```

Comment: Need that queries in db2, how to do it in db2?

Comment: check this.you had to replace dual with sysibm.sysdummy1

Comment: what do you mean by not working?what error do you get?

Comment: LPAD seems to require a constant expression for the padding size: `-123
THE PARAMETER IN POSITION n IN THE FUNCTION name MUST BE A CONSTANT OR KEYWORD`